# My MQL4 order is sent fine but then nothing happens, and no order was sent?

Tags: trading, mql4

Can this be a latency problem?

Hi! This code sometimes return me nothing after having all condition met for opening an order.

No error, or anything.

Is it possible that in some milliseconds that price has changed and order is automatically discarded?

---

Here you can see when *PlaceOrder* is called with a BUY or SELL and nothing happen before. In the first case you can see an issue with `USDCAD`, after 9 minutes another signal occurred and the EA opened correctly.

[image]
[image]

```cpp
    bool PlaceOrder(int type, int magic, int id, bool checkmargin = false)
        {
         Print("PlaceOrder called.. Type : "+TypeToStr(type));
         double entry, lot;
         color  col;
         int typet;
         int i = 0;
         while(i < NumRetries)
           {
            i += 1;
            while(IsTradeContextBusy())
               Sleep(RetryDelayInSec*1000);
            RefreshRates();
            if(type == OP_BUY)
              {
               entry = Ask;
               col   = Blue;
               typet = 2;
              }
            else
              {
               entry = Bid;
               col   = Red;
               typet = 4;
              }
            if(MathAbs(entry-Close[1]) > stoplevel)
               break;  //--Controllo che non ci siano stati spike nel prezzo (es. new impattante)
            if(LotCalculation == FixedLots)
               lot = FixedLotSize;
            else
               lot = GetLotSize(type, entry);
            Print("Try "+i+" : Open "+TypeToStr(type)+" order. Entry : "+DoubleToStr(entry,Digits)+" Lot :"+lot+" Magic :"+magic);
            if(checkmargin)
              {
               double margin_required = 2 * MarketInfo(Symbol(),MODE_MARGINREQUIRED)*lot;
               double initloss = MathCeil((InitialPL() + CommissionPerLot)*lot);
               Print("margin_required to open 2 trades : "+margin_required+" initloss : "+initloss+" AccountFreeMargin : "+AccountFreeMargin());
               if(AccountFreeMargin() <= margin_required+initloss)
                 {
                  Print("Unable to place order due to insufficient margin");
                  return(false);
                 }
              }       
            int ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(),type,lot,entry,Slippage,0,0,TradeComment,magic,0,col);     
            if(ticket <= 0)
              {
               Print("ERROR opening market order. ErrorCode:"+GetLastError());
               if(i == NumRetries)
                 {
                  Print("*** Final retry to OPEN ORDER failed ***");
                  return(false);
                 }
              }
            else
              {
               SetSLandTP(ticket, id);
               i = NumRetries;
               return(true);
              }
           }
         return(false);
        }
```

Comment: There are several lines of code between the `Print("PlaceOrder called...");` and the `OrderSend()` function which could prevent the order being sent. Try adding further `Print()` commands for further debugging (especially at the `break;`)

Comment: Thank You Paul! Distraction Errors.. the worst

Comment: Unfortunately with mq4 code, it's almost impossible to say what could have gone wrong without knowing many more details, and having an extensive error handler. Re-quotes is a very popular method to blow past traders orders and SL's. Then there's the spread an data gaps. Most trading algos completely forget about the MT4 *midnight"* server reboot/pause. Most sketchy brokers have at least 5-10 minutes trading break where you will be hit by enormous spreads, requotes or even missing quotes with gaps. They usually put this at midnight server time...but in what time zone? Check with your broker!

Comment: The code as it is would show errors associated with `OrderSend`, that is not where the problem is as the extract from the log clearly shows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle all error codes, and preferably separately from just using GetLastError() once here and there. In you code you're setting TP and SL after having checked the previous operation for error. But your code is likely to fail also here as you probably have too tight SL and/or TP's for the trading conditions under which your algo is running. (See my comments about *slippage, requotes* and *spreads* above.)

Make sure you understand and are handling all of the possible errors here:

- https://docs.mql4.com/constants/errorswarnings/errorcodes
- https://docs.mql4.com/constants/errorswarnings/enum_trade_return_codes

There are libs that can help you do this.